# Passing equals and not equals into a function

Tags: c#

I have two sections of code A and B that are identical to each other, except that A has this

```
if(x == y)
```

and B has this

```
if(x != y)
```

where x and y are integers.

I want to reduce replication of code and so wanted to put this code in a separate method.  The question is how do I pass the `==` and `!=` operators into such a method and execute it?

Comment: You should show at least a simplified version of what you're doing in the "sections". Otherwise it sounds as if you don't know how to pass a `bool` variable to a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a `Func<int, int, bool>`

```
private void MyMethod(Func<int, int, bool> checker)
{
    if(checker(3, 4))
    {
         // Do Something.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Like xor it with a bool?

```
bool negate = true;
...
if ((x == y) ^ negate)
  ...
```

In case of integer equation and inequity it can solve your problems easily.

Comment: Wonderful answer. Sometimes modern languages make me think in so complicated ways (passing an action) that I forget to think about the most simple solution!

Comment: @Matzi xoring the results with a bool is a great idea

Comment: It's not easy to read/write/know it works at a glance, though IMHO...maybe it would be better as a static method?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do like this:

```
void TheMethod(Func<int, int, bool> criterion)
{
  ...

  if (criterion(x, y))

  ...
}
```

then call with `TheMethod((x, y) => x == y);` or `TheMethod((x, y) => x != y);`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a boolean function that acceps a flag for evaluating equality or inequality:

```
bool Eval(bool enforceEquality, T x, T y)
{
   if(enforceEqality)
      return x == y
   else 
      return x != y
}
```

The name Eval could use some work, but this way you pass the flag in from outside & use it to determine which evaluation returns true.